# Running into an java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed) on server- client socket app

Tags: java, sockets

I am a very beginner Java dev (dev wannabe to be precise) and, I am trying to learn about Java sockets using a Youtube tutorial as a reference. My code seems to match everything in the video (except variables names) but, when trying to run the server and then the client sockets, I get a :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

I have tried even printing out the `local port` just to make sure I connect to the right available port but, nothing works. Is there any documentation I can look into to solve this problem? or any guidance?

This is my code this far:

Server.java

```
    public class serverSocket {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

      String message, serverResponse;

      ServerSocket serverSocket =  new ServerSocket(56789);
      System.out.print(serverSocket.getLocalPort());
      Socket acceptClientRequestSocket = serverSocket.accept();
      Scanner serverScanner = new Scanner(acceptClientRequestSocket.getInputStream());
      message = serverScanner.next();
       System.out.println(message);
      serverResponse = message.toUpperCase();

      PrintStream newMessage = new PrintStream(acceptClientRequestSocket.getOutputStream());
      newMessage.println(serverResponse);    

     }
    }
```

Client.java

```
   public class clientSocket {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        String message,outputMessage;
        Scanner clientInput =  new Scanner(System.in);
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",56789);
        Scanner incomingStream = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Enter a message");
        message = clientInput.next();
        PrintStream printClientStream=  new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        printClientStream.println(message);
        outputMessage = incomingStream.next();
        System.out.println(outputMessage);

    }
    }
```

Comment: A prior instance of your server is already running. Terminate it and wait two minutes for all the ports in TIME_WAIT state to close.